# Is there a better way to make these blue lines span the width of the text box?

Tags: css, textbox, block

On my [blog site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/)I have these horizontal blue lines and all I want them to do is span the width of the text box, and the way I did it seems to cause other issues. The only way I could get it to work was to add these funky margins. Is there a simpler way of making it the width of the text box?

```
 .date {    
padding: 10px;
margin-left: -42px;
margin-right: -40px;
padding-left: 40px;
display: block;
background: #0076a9;
```

[image]
[image]

UPDATED:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
#header, #pageWrapper, #footer {
    padding: 30px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}  
h1.logo {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
.slide img {
    opacity: 1
}
.sqs-active-slide img {
    opacity:1
}
 img {margin-bottom: 10px;}

.collection-type-gallery #slideshowWrapper .slide img {
    background-color: white !important;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.hentry {
    background: #F8F9FC;
    padding: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E2E7F5;
    border-width: 2px
}
```

Comment: Include your markup, please. Of course 'better' is subjective and negative margins are perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm with Derek S. I believe negative margins here are cool.

Comment: If you don't want negative margins, even though they are perfectly fine.. you are going to need to change the position of the 'date sections' in your html.. Right now, it inherits the padding from the text box.

Comment: You said "the way I did it seems to cause other issues"..  what other issues?

Comment: its a stock site from squarespace, with a lot of CSS that I added. It caused an issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499815/why-are-the-blue-lines-in-my-blog-jumping-out-of-the-text-box-in-mobile-view)  in mobile.

Comment: so fixing the "hentry" part now made the margins too big in mobile view

Comment: I was trying to work backwards to fix everything

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with the negative margins then if you both think its fine to have. I'm just now trying to solve the margin issue I created.

Comment: @Jeff Dowell You should include your media query CSS and also your markup in the question to receive better help.

Comment: maybe use a media query to do something different for mobile

Comment: I entered the media query I have in my css in my question above, its the `.hentry { padding: 40px;}` that fixed the blue line issue, but now it made my text margins too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your media query (or create a new one).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    .hentry {
        padding:20px;
    }

    .date{
        margin-left: -22px;
        margin-right: -20px;
        padding-left: 22px;
    }

    .collection-type-blog article header .entry-title {
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
    }

}
```

Comment: except now my date text isnt lined up with the body text

Comment: @Jeff Dowell You'll also need to adjust the padding-left on .date, see updated answer.